# what does this line indicate:- module = _("Polls") in Django CMS PollPluginPublisher

Tags: django-cms

I am trying to learn Django Cms but here is where I have stuck. IN the following code of Django CMS official documentation
Link:-http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/introduction/plugins.html

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from polls_cms_integration.models import PollPluginModel
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _


class PollPluginPublisher(CMSPluginBase):
    model = PollPluginModel  # model where plugin data are saved
    module = _("Polls")
    name = _("Poll Plugin")  # name of the plugin in the interface
    render_template = "polls_cms_integration/poll_plugin.html"

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context.update({'instance': instance})
        return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(PollPluginPublisher)  # register the plugin
```

I am unable to get the use of line module = _("Polls")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
> ```

[Django I18N documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/)

> In order to make a Django project translatable, you have to add a minimal number of hooks to your Python code and templates. These hooks are called translation strings. They tell Django: “This text should be translated into the end user’s language, if a translation for this text is available in that language.” It’s your responsibility to mark translatable strings; the system can only translate strings it knows about.
>
> ...
>
> Specify a translation string by using the function `ugettext()`. It’s convention to import this as a shorter alias, `_`, to save typing.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams but can you tell why the "module" variable is being used as it's not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: @ShashishekharHasabnis the module variable tells the cms where to group your plugin. For example, if you have an app with a lot of plugins, you'll want these plugins to be grouped under a specific name. When module is not provided then the plugins are grouped under a "Generic" name.